# UDP File Transfer Using Delphi Indy 10

Tags: delphi, indy10

I am using Delphi Xe-3 indy 10 for udp file transfer . I am passing file in small chunks and I am facing problem while transfering bigger and files other than text files.

In client when I debug the size of the file is saved wrong ,I am unable to figure out the reason. Below is the client and server code, Client send files to Server.
(I am using udp because I am working on Reliable udp.)

Problem is mentioned in the client code(send function).

Server:

```
procedure TForm2.serverUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  AData: array of Byte; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
  var

  str , len :string;
  size : word;
  index : word;

begin

   setlength(b,length(Adata));
   move(Adata[0],b[0],length(Adata));              // convert array of byte to tidbytes

   index:=0;
   setlength(Ext,b[index]);                      // get filename length
   setlength(File_data , b[index+1]);             // get file length
   index:= index+2;
   move(b[index],Ext[1],length(Ext)*2);           // copy filename
   index:= index+length(Ext)*2;
   move(b[index],File_data[0],length(File_data));      // copy file

   save.Visible:= true;
   //progressbar1.Visible:= true;
   progressbar1.Position
   memo1.Lines.Add('Receving file...->');

end;

procedure TForm2.SaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
buttonSelected : Integer;
content:integer;
begin

savedialog1.FileName := Ext;            // save file name
if savedialog1.Execute then            // save dialog opens
   try
    if FileExists(SaveDialog1.FileName) then
     begin
     if MessageDlg('Do you want to overwrite the existing file ?',
     TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation,mbYesNo,0) = IDNO then
       begin
         exit;
       end
     end;

    Strm:=TFileStream.Create(Ext,fmCreate);
    Strm.Position:=0;
    //progressbar1.Value:= 100*length(File_data)/content;                                                // set position to start
    WriteTIdBytesToStream (Strm,File_data,length(File_data),0);      // write bytes data to stream
    memo1.Lines.Add('File transmission complete...');
    finally
    strm.Free;
    save.Visible := false;
    progressbar1.Visible := false;
    end;

end;
```

Client:

```
procedure TForm1.LoadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

//openDialog1.InitialDir := GetCurrentDir;

if openDialog1.Execute then

begin
Edit1.Text     := OpenDialog1.FileName;
memo1.Lines.Add (Opendialog1.FileName);

Filename := ExtractFileName (Opendialog1.FileName);
Mem := TFileStream.Create(OpenDialog1.FileName,fmOpenRead); //connects the client

end;

{finally
opendialog1.Free;
end;
    }

end;

procedure TForm1.SendClick(Sender: TObject);
var
size : word;
index : word;
begin
index := 0;
 try
   Posi:=0;
   While Posi<Mem.Size do
   begin
   Len:=1024;
   if Mem.Size-Posi<1024 then
   begin
   Len:=Mem.Size-Posi;
   end;
   setlength(chunk,len);
   ReadTIdBytesFromStream(Mem,chunk,Len);

  size := length(chunk) + length(Filename)*2 + 2;  // it gets right sizes here , 
                                                   //chunk size is also correct
  setlength(File_data,Size);
  File_data[index] := length(Filename);
  index:= index+1;
  File_data[index]:= length(chunk);// its saved here ,value is reduced.
  index:= index+1;
  move(Filename[1],File_data[index],length(Filename)*2);
  index:= index+length(Filename)*2;
  move(chunk[0],file_data[index],length(chunk));

  client.SendBuffer('127.0.0.1',6002,File_data);
  Inc(Posi,Len);
  end;

  finally
  Mem.Free;
  Edit1.Text:='';
  Filename:='';
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
client.Bindings.Add.Port:= 0;
client.Active  := true;
end;

end.
```

Comment: If you don't have a very good reason for using UDP, you should always almost always be using TCP.  UDP packets are not guaranteed to be received, and not in any particular order.

Comment: i said i m working on building Reliable udp protocol. its  a project i need to do it.

Comment: You will have to do a lot of more work if you want to build a reliable UDP protocol. First problem is packet ordering. TCP guarantees that packet 1 is delivered first, UDP does not. UDP does retransmit pacekts and so on... The code you show here is not at all reliable. Maybe you need to study "reliable UDP" first before attempting to code anything?

Comment: No i have done that for chat . Now i was looking for file transfer through that..so tried file transfer code examples.

Comment: But Rudp is for reliablity ,not for breaking files to chunks or should i implement that thing also in Rudp?

Comment: Yea, i heard that thing before (don't know much about file transfer)but dosen't starting file streams form zero tells them the start position?It copies in same pattern as source file is(upto the level it is copied for me ).

Comment: I just want to know the problem i mentioned is it a bug or normal behaviour of udp?

Comment: Your client code is sending file data in chunks without identifying which chunks go in which order. Remember, UDP *does not* guarantee the chunks will be delivered in the same order that they were sent, and *does not* guarantee that they will be delivered at all. That is why I recommend that you switch to the TFTP protocol instead, because it *does* guarantee ordering, as well as allows missing chucks to be re-transmitted if they get lost.

Comment: Also, your server code is saving chunks only when a button is pressed, but multiple chunks could arrive before you can press the button, or while the save dialog is still visible.  You need to save each chunk inside the `OnUDPRead` event (which is triggered as each chunk arrives), so you need to prompt for the target file before receiving the first chunk, not while you are in the middle of receiving chunks.  All the more reason to switch to the TFTP protocol.

Comment: TFTP sends the filename and prompts the receiver for permission to continue before then sending the first chunk. The receiver can create the file before returning the initial reply, then receive the chunks into that file as they arrive. Indy's TFTP components handle these details for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks a lot for your help, before starting with tidtrivialftpserver i want to ask does its server component works as both client and server as tidudpserver? because i need to implement it for p2p not for client/server.

Comment: You cannot use `TIdTrivialFTPServer` as a client, only as a server.  You must use `TIdTrivialFTP` as the client.

Comment: Ok i think then for p2p i had to drop two components on one form ?so that it can react as a client or sever(send and receive) at the same time.Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indy has `TIdTrivialFTP` and `TIdTrivialFTPServer` components.  [TFTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350) is a UDP-based file transfer protocol. You should consider using that instead of creating your own custom protocol.